# EventWaitHandle signal reason

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.5, event-wait-handle

Is there any way to determine if an `EventWaitHandle` was signaled by a call to `Set();` or was timed out? an example:

```
private static EventWaitHandle ThreadWaiter =
        new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);

    private void StartLongAction()
    {
        ThreadWaiter.WaitOne(5000);

        //detect signal reason
        if(ThreadWaiter was signaled)
        {

        }
        //detect signal reason
        else if(ThreadWaiter was timedout)
        {

        }
    }

    public void HardwareEvent(EventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadWaiter.Set();
    }
```

The only option that I could think of is to hold a `bool` variable that will change on every `WaitOne()` and `Set()` call but I was wondering if the framework has a more elegant solution

Comment: Of course, WaitOne() returns a *bool* to tell you.

Comment: the returnvalue (== bool) of WaitOne specifies if the handle was signaled or not

Comment: Since it looks like you are going to run this on a background thread and you are waiting on a hardware event, is there any harm in just letting it sit until you receive the event? That is, why do you need a timeout.  There may be a different solution with other synchronization mechanisms if you can't just wait.

Comment: @HansPassant & Martin thank you, I some how missed it in the [MSDN class description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)